# Integrating Azure B2C Authentication with .NET Framework 4.6.2

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, .net-4.8

I'm working on a legacy project that uses .NET Framework 4.6.2, and I need to integrate Azure AD B2C for user authentication. While I've successfully set up Azure B2C and implemented the authentication with .NET Core, I'm struggling to achieve the same integration with .NET Framework 4.6.2.

I'd appreciate guidance on how to start this integration, as well as any code examples, tutorials, or best practices that can help me set up Azure B2C authentication with .NET Framework 4.6.2. Even a simple code snippet for a login button would be extremely helpful. I understand that this is an older technology stack, but I believe it's still feasible.

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview)? The article [Quickstart: Set up sign in for an ASP.NET application using Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/quickstart-web-app-dotnet) targets ASP.NET, not ASP.NET Core

Comment: Are you getting a response?  If so what status code (200 OK or 400/500 error)?  If you are not getting a response than most likely you are failing TLS.  TLS uses an encryption algorithm (inside a certificate) and unless you use Net 4.7.1 or later you are going to have issues.  Net 4.7.1 uses operating System for TLS which should work (unless you are using an old OS).  Only valid TLS versions are 1.2 and 1.3.  The encryption algorithm depends on the TLS version and the certificate. A IIS server is old and does not work with newer encryption modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos and jdweng for the comments.

As mentioned by Panagiotis Kanavos, we have a [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/quickstart-web-app-dotnet) which explains the clear steps to Integrate ADB2C in a Framework Application (GitHub samples).

> guidance on how to start this integration

- If you want to make it easier, follow the below steps.

You can Integrate Azure ADB2C directly from VS while creating the Web App Template.

- Select the Authentication as `Microsoft Identity platform`.

[image]

- As soon as the Web App template is created, you will get an option to Install components related to `msidentity`.

[image]

- Select the correct tenant related to `ADB2C` => click on `Create new` and continue with next steps.

[image]

- This step will register a new app in `App registrations` section in ADB2C.

[image]

- Here I have created an app with name `ASPFramework`, you can check the same in the ADB2C.

***Visual Studio:***
[image]

***In Portal:***
[image]

- Continue with the next steps.
- Below changes are made in the WebApp.

[image]

***Dependency Configuration progress:***

```cs
Retrieved B2C Sign-up/Sign-in Policy with id: B2C_1_SUSI
Connecting to Microsoft identity platform dependency identityapp1 in the project...
Updating remote app registration: dotnet msidentity --update-app-registration --username **********.com --tenant-id ******** --client-id ****** --enable-id-token --json --instance https://login.microsoftonline.com/ --redirect-uris https://localhost:44344/signin-oidc
Successfully updated app registration ASPFramework (********)
Adding settings to C:\Users\****\ADB2CASPFramework\ADB2CASPFramework\Web.config...
Complete. Microsoft identity platform identityapp1 is configured.
```

- Check `StartupAuth.cs` under App_Start,`Web.config`,`.csproj` for the automatically Integrated code and packages.

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: i have to ask shouldn't  be that i get this image 
https://pasteboard.co/RE34oCRCcXMv.png
with the custom css and html instead of this microsoft login form ? 
because on .net 7 i was able to recreate it but with your example its using microsoft login form not the demo login ?

Comment: @ice_hell - Yes you can implement custom css, I just gave the sample code.